# how linq query will work on xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have xml like below

```
 <BrowserMix>
            <BrowserProfile Percentage="10">
              <Browser Name="Internet Explorer 10.0" MaxConnections="6">
                <Headers>
                  <Header Name="User-Agent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)" />
                  <Header Name="Accept" Value="*/*" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Language" Value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Encoding" Value="GZIP" />
                </Headers>
              </Browser>
            </BrowserProfile>
            <BrowserProfile Percentage="85">
              <Browser Name="Internet Explorer 9.0" MaxConnections="6">
                <Headers>
                  <Header Name="User-Agent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)" />
                  <Header Name="Accept" Value="*/*" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Language" Value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Encoding" Value="GZIP" />
                </Headers>
              </Browser>
            </BrowserProfile>
            <BrowserProfile Percentage="5">
              <Browser Name="WinPhone8" MaxConnections="6">
                <Headers>
                  <Header Name="User-Agent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)" />
                  <Header Name="Accept" Value="*/*" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Language" Value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
                  <Header Name="Accept-Encoding" Value="GZIP" />
                </Headers>
              </Browser>
            </BrowserProfile>
          </BrowserMix>
```

I want to get value attribute of "Percentage" and Browser Name using linq query? Thanks in advance?

And 
Linq query is

```
 var browserQuery = (from dt in xdoc.Descendants("Root").AsEnumerable()
                               select new
                               {
                                   BrowserMix = dt.Attribute("Percentage").Value.ToString(),
                                   Name = dt.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString()
                               });
```

I am always getting no enumeration yield result..

Comment: Have you loaded that beauty into an `XDocument`?

Comment: Yes i loaded it as <root> above xml <root>

Comment: Please edit your post to include your Linq to XML code.

Comment: Update linq code. and why are you downvoted ?

Comment: Removed downvote and flagging for a mod to reevaluate if your edit makes it a better suited for SO. Andrew Barber's note sums up the reason for the downvotes. Don't take it personally,  it's only a matter of getting the better questions on the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// untested 
var browserQuery = xdoc.Root.Descendants("BrowserProfile")
                       .Select(dt => new {
                          BrowserMix = dt.Attribute("Percentage").Value,
                          Name = dt.Element("Browser").Attribute("Name").Value
                       });
```

Couple of points to note:

- Start query from `.Root`
- `Descendants` and `Elements` return `IEnumerable<XElement>` so you don't need to include `.AsEnumerable()`
- `XElement.Value` property returns string by default so `.ToString()` is not necessary

Comment: Gives "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Maybe loading the document the way you did does not require `Root`. Try that just to let me know. It appears @Tim did not use `Root` and that may be the issue ...???

Comment: Also, I see additional comments above regarding namespace, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your posted code:

1. You don't need to use `AsEnumerable()` on `XDocument.Descendants(XName)`, as this returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` collection already.
2. You need to specify the element that has the attribute you're looking for; since you started with a collection of all elements named Root, it will look for those attributes in Root.
3. `.Value` returns a string, so there's no need to call `.ToString()` on it.

The reason why you're not getting any results is because of #2 (there is no Percentage or Name attribute on Root).

Try this:

```
// xml is a string containing the xml posted in the question
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var browserQuery = from dt in xdoc.Descendants("BrowserProfile")
                   select new
                   {
                       Percentage = dt.Attribute("Percentage").Value,
                       Name = dt.Element("Browser").Attribute("Name").Value
                   };
```

What this code does is:

1. Gets a collection of all the BrowserProfile elements (and their children).
2. It returns a anonymous type collection that has the value of the Percentage attribute and the value of the Name element.  Note that the Browser element is used to get to the Name attribute.

You can then loop through this collection:

```
for each (var browser in browserQuery)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Browser {0} has {1} percent", browser.Name, browser.Percentage);
}
```

**EDIT**

To handle the namespace, use `XNamespace` like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010";
```

Then add it before the element names:

```
var browserQuery = from dt in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "BrowserProfile")
                   select new
                   {
                       Percentage = dt.Attribute("Percentage").Value,
                       Name = dt.Element(ns + "Browser").Attribute("Name").Value
                   };
```

Comment: No luck..Gives result as "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: How are you creating the XDocument?  I tested the code above with the XML you posted and it worked as expected - I got a collection of 3 objects.

Comment: I added a line to the my code showing how I created the XDocument for my test.

Comment: Exact XML is like <Root>
  <BrowserProfile Percentage="10" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
   Browser profile having xmlns ...is it creating problem

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to handle the namespace issue.